# How to copy lines from one file and write them in other file using python?

Tags: python, io, copy

I have sequence of data as shown below:

```
XXXXXXX
DATA = 1,2,3,4,5,6,
       7,8,9,10,11,12,14,
       15 
XXXXXXX
```

if there is continuation line ends with "," else it has no comma",".

How can I copy only DATA from given file and write it in other file? Please help me!

Comment: Open your data file for reading, an output file for writing. Loop through the data in your data file and write the required lines to the output file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import re

data_file = open("data.txt", 'r')
data = data_file.read()

search = re.search("DATA\s\=\s((.*\d.+\,?\n)+)", data)
print search.group(1)
```

Comment: can we use filename.readlines()?

   data = data_file.readlines()

Comment: Can you please suggest me the syntax which does the same functionality using .readlines() method.

Comment: You can just loop over the lines looking for a comma at the end of each line until they stop then.